# How do I SELECT the row with maximum value for an attribute in SQL

Tags: sql, row, max

This is my table

```
BRANCH    NUMBER_OF_PHONES
B001      3
B002      2
B003      1
B004      2
```

How can I select the row that has the highest number of phones for the branch?

```
BRANCH    NUMBER_OF_PHONES
B001      3
```

This is my SQL query that generated the first table:

```
SELECT BRANCH_PHONES.BRANCH_NO AS 'BRANCH', COUNT(BRANCH_PHONES.BRANCH_TEL) as 'NUMBER_OF_PHONE_NUMBERS'
FROM [Practices].dbo.BRANCH BRANCH, [Practices].dbo.BRANCH_PHONES BRANCH_PHONES 
WHERE BRANCH.BRANCH_NO = BRANCH_PHONES.BRANCH_NO 
GROUP BY BRANCH_PHONES.BRANCH_NO;
```

Comment: Is it MySQL or SQL Server ?

Comment: @FabienTheSolution Are these the only two possibilities? :p

Comment: @popovitsj you're right :)

Comment: if Branch Id is Unique then its so simple, use subquery   
  `Select BRANCH_PHONES.BRANCH_NO AS 'BRANCH', BRANCH_PHONES.BRANCH_TEL) as 'NUMBER_OF_PHONE_NUMBERS' FROM [Practices].dbo.BRANCH BRANCH, [Practices].dbo.BRANCH_PHONES BRANCH_PHONES where BRANCH_PHONES.BRANCH_NO = (Select Max(BRANCH_PHONES.BRANCH_TEL) FROM [Practices].dbo.BRANCH BRANCH, [Practices].dbo.BRANCH_PHONES)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the example data you showed is the result of your first attempt (the query you posted).

You want the branch that has the most phones. You didn't specify your DBMS, but if it is MySQL you can use `LIMIT` like this. Sort by COUNT(Phones), then only show the first row of the result set.

```
SELECT Branche, COUNT(Phones) FROM Branch
GROUP BY Branche
ORDER BY COUNT(Phones) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Note: this will give an arbitrary result if there is a tie for the most phones.